# PostgreSQL 10 partition by list using enums

Tags: postgresql, enums, partitioning, postgresql-10

I am trying to partition my table using enum column and I am encountering a somewhat strange behaviour.

```
create type positivity as enum (
    'POSITIVE',
    'NEGATIVE'
);

create table test (id int, polarity positivity) partition by list (polarity);
create table test_1 partition of test for values in ('POSITIVE');
create table test_2 partition of test for values in ('NEGATIVE');

explain select * from test where polarity = 'NEGATIVE';
```

For this code this is what I get for output of explain:
[image]

My question is why is it working like that and is this a bug or a feature in postgres?

EDIT: Adding constraints manually improves the query plan and that way I've got what I wanted (but I am still wandering about the behaviour explained above):

```
alter table test_1 add constraint test_1_check check(polarity='POSITIVE');
alter table test_2 add constraint test_1_check check(polarity='NEGATIVE');
```

New query plan for the same explain command:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's usually better to post execution plans as plain (formatted!) text  and in most cases it's better to use **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** instead of a simple `explain`

Comment: Might be a bug with enums. It works as expected if `polarity` is defined as `text`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yeah, sorry for not putting text :( It seems like a bug to me too, but i am to lazy to do everything they require of me just to report this bug

Comment: You could post this question on the Postgres general mailing list (rather then generating a "real" bug report) - if it turns out to be a bug (and not a case of "not-yet-implemented") I'm pretty sure the developers will pick that up

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I submitted the issue, seems like there is similar issue concerning arrays also, if you are interested look at: 
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2b20c220-50cb-3fae-da57-92e8cb3675dd%40lab.ntt.co.jp

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this in mid 2018, the fix hasn't made it into release yet; I'm still seeing it happen on 10.4.

Here's the commit for the fix, which appears it is being reviewed this month - 
https://commitfest.postgresql.org/17/1591/

Comment: Fix for this will appear in 10.5, which will be released later this week.

Here is the development version of release notes, which mentions an item for the fix for this issue ("Fix handling of partition keys whose data type uses a polymorphic btree operator class, such as arrays"): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-10-5.html